# Firefox: hover overflow:auto issue in spell check for text

Tags: css, firefox, hover, overflow, spell-checking

overflow:auto is not working properly in Firefox to spell check for typed text in text area.
When I right click on incorrect text and select correct text from suggested texts, it does not show correct selected text.

CSS code used:

```
div.mystyle:hover {
overflow: auto; 
}
```

[See Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/vn29/u4F22/)

It works fine in chrome.

Is there any workaround for it? 
Note: I need this class should be overflow auto for some other reason.

Comment: why you using the hover effect?if you remove the hover from the class its working fine in firefox

Comment: As I mentioned in description, I need it for some other purpose.
I have posted this question just I would like to know How can I fix it? or Why is this not working with Firefox only?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the css you are using. You are assigning it to the div **NOT the textarea**. The textarea scroll is a default setting in chrome. Is it the scrollbar at the textarea you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set that style dynamically to  div. We set that style using jquery,

Script,

```
 $(".mystyle").hover(function () {
     $(this).attr("style", "overflow:auto");
 });
```

Here is the working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u4F22/9/)